# In Mark 14:44 why did Judas betray Jesus with a kiss?

Tags: jesus, gospels, symbolism, messiah, judas

Why did Judas betray Jesus with a kiss?  The simplest explanation is of course the one we find in Matthew and Mark.  This was the prearranged sign by which Judas identified Jesus to the arresting soldiers.  Mark records this in chapter 14,

> 43 Just as he was speaking, Judas, one of the Twelve, appeared. With
>   him was a crowd armed with swords and clubs, sent from the chief
>   priests, the teachers of the law, and the elders.
>
> 44 **Now the betrayer had arranged a signal with them: “The one I kiss
>   is the man; arrest him** and lead him away under guard.” 45 Going at
>   once to Jesus, Judas said, “Rabbi!” and kissed him. 46 The men seized
>   Jesus and arrested him.

Matthew records this in chapter 26,

> 47 While he was still speaking, Judas, one of the Twelve, arrived.
>   With him was a large crowd armed with swords and clubs, sent from the
>   chief priests and the elders of the people. 48 **Now the betrayer had
>   arranged a signal with them: “The one I kiss is the man; arrest him.”**
>   49 Going at once to Jesus, Judas said, “Greetings, Rabbi!” and kissed
>   him.
>
> 50 Jesus replied, “Do what you came for, friend.”
>
> Then the men stepped forward, seized Jesus and arrested him.

That explanation, however, leaves a major issue still unanswered. ***Why a kiss?*** There are certainly far less intimate ways to identify someone to be betrayed.  Why did Judas chose to identify Jesus **with a kiss**?

Comment: Possibly related: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/35667/in-john-1326-is-judas-supposed-to-represent-judah

Answer (score 8):

**Short Answer**

The answer has everything to do with Psalms 2 and Jesus' claim to be king.  Judas chose to sarcastically betray Jesus, the "supposed Son of God”, with a kiss. His kiss is deeply ironic. As with the soldiers in the crucifixion, He mocks Jesus in his claim to be the rightful king of Israel.

**Long Answer**

When Jesus entered Jerusalem on a donkey, just days before his betrayal, he was publically proclaiming himself the Christ/Messiah, the Son of David, the rightful king of Israel.  The crowd of people present that day certainly understood his actions. Their interpretation is found recorded in each of the four Gospels.  In Matthew they shout, “Hosanna to the Son of David!” In Mark they say, “Blessed is the coming kingdom of our father David!” In Luke we hear them proclaim, “Blessed is the king who comes in the name of the Lord!  And in John they cry, “Blessed is the King of Israel.”

Why did the people connect Jesus’ entrance into Jerusalem on a donkey with an implicit claim to the throne? Matthew and John of course point to a prophetic fulfillment of Zachariah 9:9,

> Rejoice greatly, O daughter of Zion!
>
> Shout aloud, O daughter of Jerusalem!
>
> Behold, your king is coming to you;
>
> righteous and having salvation is he,
>
> humble and mounted on a donkey,
>
> on a colt, the foal of a donkey.

And this is typically where our answers end.

But there’s an even bigger reason to connect Jesus’ entrance into Jerusalem with his claim to be king.  We know that the act of riding a mule into Jerusalem was the sign by which Solomon was proclaimed king of Israel.  This event is found in 1 Kings 1.  The ride on David’s mule is there emphasized, being repeated three times. This is a particularly crucial event in Israel’s history.  It’s Israel’s first dynastic succession.  Though Saul had been the first king of Israel, he had no dynasty.  He and his sons were killed and the rule passed to a new line in David.  It’s not until Solomon’s coronation in 1 Kings 1, however, that we find David’s royal linage established.  And it’s established in none other than Solomon’s ride into Jerusalem on David’s mule.

Given this events historical and symbolic importance, Its likely that it was repeated in all subsequent coronation ceremonies.  In the same way George Washington’s personal decision to swear on a Bible has been repeated in all subsequent presidential inaugurations, so the riding into Jerusalem on a mule formed the basis for future coronations. Jesus, by entering Jerusalem on a donkey, appears to be acting out a royal coronation ceremony which the people recognized.

In this single act, Jesus publicly proclaimed himself to be the restoration of the fallen house of David.  In 2 Samuel 7, God had made an eternal promise to David that one of his sons would sit on Israel’s throne. And yet by the time of the Gospels, David’s throne had been empty for more than five hundred years.  Psalms 89, bemoans this situation.  In it God says, “

> Once for all I have sworn by my holiness;
>
> I will not lie to David.
>
> His offspring shall endure forever,
>
> his throne as long as the sun before me.
>
> Like the moon it shall be established forever,
>
> a faithful witness in the skies.” (89:35-37)

And yet the Psalmist grieves the fact that God has now

> cast off and rejected;
>
> you are full of wrath against your anointed.
>
> You have renounced the covenant with your servant;
>
> you have defiled his crown in the dust. (89:38-39).

Psalms 89 looks back to the original promise made to David in 2 Samuel 7.  And its 2 Samuel 7 which is especially important for our understanding of David’s successors and thus Jesus’ self understanding as He enters into Jerusalem.  It explains what it means for Jesus to be the “Christ,” “the Son of David” and yes, even “the Son of God.”

In 2 Samuel 7, David tells Nathan the prophet of his plans to build a “house” for God. David has built himself a “house of cedar” and thus finds it unbearable that the ark of God should still reside in a tent.  Nathan endorses the plan but then suddenly changes his mind when he receives a message from God. God says He doesn’t want David to build him a “house.” Instead God promises to make a “house” (i.e. dynasty – note the play on words), for David.

> Moreover, the Lord declares to you that the Lord will make you a
>   house. When your days are fulfilled and you lie down with your
>   fathers, I will raise up your offspring after you, who shall come from
>   your body, and I will establish his kingdom. He shall build a house
>   for my name, and I will establish the throne of his kingdom forever. I
>   will be to him a father, and he shall be to me a son. When he commits
>   iniquity, I will discipline him with the rod of men, with the stripes
>   of the sons of men, but my steadfast love will not depart from him, as
>   I took it from Saul, whom I put away from before you. And your house
>   and your kingdom shall be made sure forever before me. Your throne
>   shall be established forever.’” (2 Samuel 7:11-16)

Note that the Son of David has a special relationship to God. The king is here described as God’s son. By this point you should be recognizing the echoes in the Gospels.  In the Gospels, God himself calls Jesus his “Son” while Jesus calls God his “Father.” In reading 2 Samuel 7 it’s also quite natural to see a reference to Solomon, since Solomon, the first son of David, did in fact build a “house” or temple for God.  But it’s also important to see in this promise a note to Jesus’ self understanding. Jesus first act, after his entrance into Jerusalem (again, in the manner of Solomon’s coronation) is to inspect and “cleanse” the temple.  The establishment of a “house” for God is the special prerogative of David’s son. Jesus acts accordingly.  And the people respond with appropriate anticipation.

The problem, however, is that Jesus’ coronation doesn’t occur in the way the people expect. Jesus is crucified which would suggest that Jesus was just a pretender, a false claimant to David’s throne.  But that’s not how Mark and the other Gospel writers see it.  They do indeed place Jesus on the throne but it’s ironically the cross, the moment of Jesus’ greatest glory.   We know this is how the Gospel writers see it because of the details they choose to emphasize.

There’s a special turning point in each of the first three Gospels where Jesus asks his disciples the question everyone has been asking. Who is Jesus?  Jesus ask them, “Who do you say that I am?” (Mark 8:29, Matt. 16:15, Luke 9:20)  Peter declares, “You are the Anointed one.”  In other words, Peter says you are “David’s son, the Christ, the messiah, the king, the rightful heir to the throne.”  It’s a significant hair-raising announcement.  And it’s with this announcement that Jesus turns his attention to Jerusalem and his ultimate destiny.  Jesus warns them not to tell anyone what Peter has just said and at the same time begins to teach them that he will be rejected, killed and three days later rise again.  The disciples, however, choke on this prediction.  Peter rebukes him.  When he said “Christ” he clearly didn’t mean “loser.”  Instead he meant a royal kick-ass leader who would free Israel from its foreign oppressors.  But Jesus in-turn rebukes Peter, teaching his disciples that to save ones life is to lose it and to lose ones life is to save it.  This pattern is repeated two more times in the journey to Jerusalem.  When Jesus predicts his death, the disciples express pride in their earthly position and Jesus in turn must once again adjust their perspective through a paradoxical teaching.  To be the greatest you must become the least.  To be first you must be last.  To rule you must become a servant.

The last example of this pattern occurs when James and John approach Jesus with a request to sit on his right and left in his glory. Jesus has just told them he is going to Jerusalem to die but they apparently still believe he’s going up to sit on a golden throne. Jesus, however, knows that his glory is the cross and his questions to them specifically points to that. “Are you able to drink the cup that I drink, or to be baptized with the baptism with which I am baptized?”  They, not at all understanding what’s he’s talking about, nod their heads with blank stares, saying that they are able.  But Jesus says, “to sit at my right hand or at my left is not mine to grant, but it is for those for whom it has been prepared.” (Matt. 20:23, Mark 10:40)

This is significant because the only place we find anyone on Jesus right and left in the Gospels is in the crucifixion.  Mark 15:27 says, “they crucified two robbers with him, one on his right and one on his left.”  Its clear that when the disciples ask to sit with Jesus in his glory, Jesus points them to the cross.  The cross is his glory.  The placing of the thieves on Jesus right and left comes significantly at the culmination of a long list of coronation elements (15:16-27).  With Pilates order to have Jesus crucified, Mark tells us that the soldiers lead Jesus into the praetorium and there assembled the whole battalion before him. In this act Mark’s original readers would have heard echoes of the coronation of Caesar who was himself proclaimed Lord through the vote of the praetorian guard.  Mark then tells us that they clothed him in a purple cloak (a color only rulers could legally wear) and put a crown of thorns on his head.  They saluted him, “Hail, King of the Jews,” on bended knee in mock homage.  They post his charge, “the King of the Jews.”

The Gospel writers find a further irony in the “sarcasm” of the soldiers act. Jesus is indeed receiving the kingdom in the cross. In losing his life, he’s saving it. In serving, he’s becoming Lord.  This is truly his coronation.  His inauguration. Jesus’ crown is in fact bestowed in the crucifixion.

So what does this have to do with Judas’ kiss?  The answer is found in Psalms 2.  It’s one of the psalters coronation hymns and as such it was sung at the inauguration of each new davidic king. It tells us something important about the historic coronation ceremony but in that it also tells us about the ironic coronation of Jesus found in the Gospels. Read Psalms 2 with that in mind.

> Why do the nations rage
>
> and the peoples plot in vain?
>
> The kings of the earth set themselves,
>
> and the rulers take counsel together,
>
> against the Lord and against his **Anointed**, saying,
>
> “Let us burst their bonds apart
>
> and cast away their cords from us.”
>
> He who sits in the heavens laughs;
>
> the Lord holds them in derision.
>
> Then he will speak to them in his wrath,
>
> and terrify them in his fury, saying,
>
> “As for me, **I have set my King
>
> on Zion, my holy hill.”**
>
> I will tell of the decree:
>
> The Lord said to me, **“You are my Son;
>
> today I have begotten you.**
>
> Ask of me, and I will make the nations your heritage,
>
> and the ends of the earth your possession.
>
> You shall break them with a rod of iron
>
> and dash them in pieces like a potter’s vessel.”
>
> Now therefore, O kings, be wise;
>
> be warned, O rulers of the earth.
>
> Serve the Lord with fear,
>
> and rejoice with trembling.
>
> **Kiss the Son,**
>
> lest he be angry, and you perish in the way,
>
> for his wrath is quickly kindled.
>
> Blessed are all who take refuge in him.

“Kiss the Son…”  Some translations hide the explicit connection by rendering it “do homage to the son.”  The action is of course homage but the literal verb is “kiss.”  And the word kiss is relatively rare in the Old Testament, least of all an imperative to kiss the son/the anointed king.

Is there a connection to Judas and Jesus here?  I think there absolutely is.  We know that the disciples recognized Jesus as the christ, the king, the son of David.  We saw this in Matthew 16, Mark 8 and Luke 9. They went to Jerusalem to see Jesus established on the throne.  They knew the davidic coronation script.  They knew what it meant for Jesus to enter Jerusalem riding on a donkey.  But for some reason Judas lost faith.  I think in light of the Gospels it’s quit probable that Judas couldn’t get over Jesus’ rejection of traditional messiah role. He realized there would be no earthly glory and thus he chose to sarcastically betray Jesus, the supposed “son”, with a kiss.  His kiss is deeply ironic. As with the soldiers, He mocks Jesus in his claim to be the rightful king of Israel.  And yet in the Gospels we find it is the Lord who turns his sarcasm into an further layer of irony and its is the Lord who enjoys the last laugh.

Comment: I think you're half right.  You've got the prophetic part,  but you're missing the pragmatic reasons that Judas had in the moment. I find it hard to believe that he was consciously being sarcastic. Judas once again fulfills prophecy but is doing it, as it often happens,  completely unintentionally.

Comment: @JoshuaBigbee, I'm not failing to see the pragmatic reason. I've referenced it in the question. Judas "kissed" Jesus to identify him to the arresting soldiers. This was absolutely necessary in an age before photography. But that's all the gospels say. It does not say that the soldiers were hiding. It says that the soldiers arrived with him. It might be that they were laying in wait for the signal but that's not specifically in the text.

Comment: @JoshuaBigbee, I've shown how Judas very well could have seen the kiss as more than pragmatic. It would be wrong to say that the disciples knew nothing of Old Testament prophecy regarding the messiah. The very fact that they followed Jesus and considered him "the Christ" indicates that they believed him to be the prophesied and expected King of Israel. The crowds reaction to Jesus entrance into Jerusalem on a donkey also indicates that they knew the prophecy and what significance it held for the restored house of David.

Comment: @JoshuaBigbee, Psalms 2 is the most prominent psalm about the coronation of God's "anointed" ruler. If the disciples understood Jesus as the "anointed" they would have been fully aware and expecting the rule of the "son" predicted in that passage. So also Judas, who was there when Peter proclaimed Jesus "the Christ."  But Judas in the end betrays Jesus with a kiss. You really think there is no intended irony in it?

Answer (score 6):

> Why a kiss? There are certainly far less intimate ways to identify someone. Why was the kiss chosen as their signal?

A kiss was a common greeting among friends (cp. [Rom. 16:16](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Rom&c=16&v=16&t=KJV#s=t_conc_1062016); [1 Cor. 16:20](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=1Co&c=16&v=20&t=KJV#s=t_conc_1078020); [2 Cor. 13:12](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=2Co&c=13&v=12&t=KJV#s=t_conc_1091012); [1 Thes. 5:26](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=1Th&c=5&v=26&t=KJV#s=t_conc_1116026); [1 Pet. 5:14](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=1Pe&c=5&v=14&t=KJV#s=t_conc_1156014)). Since Judas was one of Jesus' twelve original apostles, they would have shared a *vinculum amicitiae*, and a kiss would have been demonstrative of such.

In fact, the Greek word [φίλημα](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G5370&t=KJV), meaning "kiss," is derived from the root φίλ- which has connotations of love and friendship.<sup>**(1)**</sup> Some common words occurring in the Greek New Testament that derive from the same root are:

- the verb [φιλέω](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=G5368&t=KJV), meaning "to love"
- the noun [φίλος](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=G5384&t=KJV), meaning "friend"

---

**Footnotes**

<sup>**(1)**</sup> See the Perseus [search results](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=start&lookup=fil&lang=greek) for a list of many other words sharing the same root φιλ-.

Comment: +1 Very true! A kiss of greeting was not unusual. But it's clearly strange for someone who is acting as enemy and not a friend. Judas could have pointed out Jesus or tapped him on the shoulder.  Given the ironic coronation of Jesus' crucifixion in Mark and the many allusions to scripture, the fact that a kiss was chosen as a signal to betray Jesus appears to be far more significant than a simple greeting.

Comment: "But it's clearly strange for someone who is acting as enemy and not a friend." <- It is true that Jesus knew that Judas would betray him (probably because Jesus was God). However, I don't recall scripture suggesting that Judas knew that Jesus knew that he (Judas) would betray him. So, there would have been no reason for Judas to have acted as an enemy when he didn't know that Judas suspected him to be an enemy. Instead, he attempted to act like a friend, because he thought Jesus didn't know any better.

Comment: Why would Judas need to act like a friend?  The kiss isn't a ruse. According to John, Judas brought a cohort of soldiers (600 men) and Jesus instantly recognizes the action for what it is. All that the gospels say is that the kiss was a signal to identify Jesus to the arresting soldiers. And that clearly did not require an act of friendship. The kiss is ironic/sarcastic.  Very much in line with the irony in crucifixion.  Judas is mocking Jesus. The question is why is he mocking him?  The answer is found in Jesus' claim to be the Christ and the expected coronation of Jesus in Jerusalem.

Comment: @MatthewMiller you're assuming the soldiers were marching in right behind him.  They easily could have been hanging back until Judas confirmed that Jesus was there and the signal to rush in was the kiss. A far more reasonable solution. Thus Judas did have to feign friendship until he knew the target was in place for the trap. This is pretty standard procedure for such operations in law enforcement with undercover stings. Confirm target, signal,  move in.

Answer (score 1):

In my eyes, Judas' kiss is a picture of their friendship. Hence, Jesus says "Do what you came for, **friend**." This idea of friendship and brotherhood placed side by side with the betrayal aspect amplifies the hurt and pain Jesus would feel and go on to feel later on. (Although, the ultimate pain was when God the Father turns His face away from Jesus, Jesus does also feel forsaken by Judas, Peter, and the rest of the disciples for that matter.)

However, the key to understanding why Judas kissed Jesus, I think lies in how Jesus responds in Luke 22:48. Jesus says “Judas, would you betray the Son of Man with a kiss?” In other words, would you forsake and inflict pain on the One whom you claim to love. I think it is a magnificent portrait of the majority of people in the Church today. You say that you love me, yet you grieve me and the Holy Spirit.

In my mind, I can see God saying, "Be an atheist and reject me, express your hatred in words and actions, but please do not say you love in words and hate me and my law in action." Be consistent, He asks, for it is easier to be hated and rejected by a stranger than to be betrayed by a family member or a loved one who promises they love you with words, and hates you with their actions.

Therefore, I think Judas' kiss was prophetic. It was an example of how many self-proclaimed Christians and "friends" of Christ claim to love Him, yet stab Him in the back. Every time we, as Christians, break His law and grieve the Holy Spirit, we inflict more pain on Him than we can ever imagine. And it hurts Him that much more when it comes from us.

I believe that everything is in the Bible for reason. Therefore, I believe an intimate kiss does a splendid job of reminding us that everyday we call ourselves "followers of Christ" and yet sin against Him consciously and repeatedly, we kiss Him as a friend would and betray Him as an enemy would.

God help us.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  Please consider [registering an account](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) to fully take advantage of what this site has to offer.  Also, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and in particular what constitutes a good answer.   Your answer is pretty good as is, but would be greatly enhanced by referencing some sources that support your interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

### A 'Kiss'

To begin with, this is probably closer to the French *[faire la bise](https://www.thelocal.fr/userdata/images/article/cb20b4a954d6d470d1ddf19919060cfddfc68adc9af183c8bd2d7c57d42103e7.jpg)* than a 'kiss on the cheek' proper.

φιλη**μα**, coming from the primitive verb φιλεω ("to love/have fondness for") means "love-gesture" put simply (a show of love, such as any kind of embrace, hug, or kiss proper). It is far more likely something like [this](https://youtu.be/jqkqc2-iteQ?t=3932) than what we call a 'kiss.' In other words, the word doesn't necessitate this understanding of 'kiss' as in English.

I am suggesting that it is, *if anything*, closer to the English word "fondle" (not as to intensity but genericness) than something as specific as "kiss." Indeed the etymology of "fondle" supports this, as it, like *phileo* and *phileema*, shares a root verb and noun relationship of 'to be fond,' 'fondling,' (one that is shown fondness) and 'to fondle.' The inherent ambiguity of 'fondle,' in other words, is similar to the ambiguity of to give someone a φιλημα—the words 'fondle's' having been defiled by usage in almost exclusively perverse, sexually intrusive or even violent context notwithstanding.

So this simple embrace or 'kiss of peace' was probably just a common greeting at that time (given how simple and ubiquitous a gesture it is), **especially among** those who felt the need to preserve unity and a sense of love between members of **the church.** I for my part find a kiss on the cheek with another man's wife (something surely not excluded from what is quite clearly intended to be devoid entirely of all sexuality, a simple gesture of Christian unity and love) for instance, hard to reconcile with first century Palestine's attitude and climate when it comes to interrelationships between men and women.

Answer (score 1):

There may be two practical reasons why a kiss was decided upon by the betrayer and those wishing to have Jesus taken captive.

1. Jesus was known for sometimes being on the verge of a mob capturing him or starting to throw stones at him, then strangely slipping out of their sight, and their grasp. Two examples of that are found in John 8:59 and Luke 4:28-30, and the reason for this is given in Scripture:

> "Yet no-one seized him, because his time had not yet come" - John
> 8:20. "Jesus replied, 'The hour has come for the Son of Man to be
> glorified'." - John 12:23

It was only when the time for his betrayal approached that Jesus would not use ways and means to escape being captured and killed. There was an exact time for him to die, although many men wanted to kill him before then. However, Judas, and Christ's enemies, knew he had evaded capture before, and needed a way of being sure they captured the right person. And the attempt would be made at night, which brings us to the second reason.

2. Judas knew that during that week Jesus was likely to be found with the disciples on the Mount of Olives of an evening. As Luke tells us:

> "Each day Jesus was teaching at the temple, and each evening he went
> out to spend the night on the hill called the Mount of Olives" Luke
> 21:37 NIV

Although the night of the betrayal happened at Passover when there had to be a full moon, even in moonlight there would be shadows, dips and gulleys. It might also have been cloudy or become cloudy at the crucial time when Judas led the troops up the Mount of Olives. The soldiers would have flame-torches, with lots of flickerings. As only Judas could be sure to correctly identify which out of the 12 men had to be captured, he had to identify Christ with no ambiguity, Pointing, while exclaiming, "There he is!" just would not do. Further, he would be the only person in the approaching group who could walk straight up to Jesus without being stopped.

Therefore, the agreed sign to identify Jesus that night in the Garden of Gethsemane was a kiss of greeting. Sensible, from the point of view of his enemies.

Answer (score 0):

The sign of betrayal (being παραδίδωμι [handed over](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G3860&t=KJV)), was to be a φιλέω; that is, [a kiss](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G5368&t=KJV). Yet the act of betrayal is described as κατεφίλησεν, [to kiss much, kiss again and again, kiss tenderly](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G2705&t=KJV):

> Now the betrayer had given them a sign, saying, “The one I will kiss is the man. Seize him and lead him away under guard.” (Mark 14:44) [ESV]
>
> δεδώκει δὲ ὁ παραδιδοὺς αὐτὸν σύσσημον αὐτοῖς λέγων ὃν ἂν **φιλήσω** αὐτός ἐστιν κρατήσατε αὐτὸν καὶ ἀπάγετε ἀσφαλῶς
>
> And when he came, he went up to him at once and said, “Rabbi!” And he kissed him.
>   (Mark 14:45)
>
> καὶ ἐλθὼν εὐθὺς προσελθὼν αὐτῷ λέγει ῥαββί καὶ **κατεφίλησεν** αὐτόν

In the translation of Israel's history, LXX translators used καταφιλέω 13 times:

- After pursuing Jacob, Laban confronts him complaining he wasn't able to kiss his children and daughters (Genesis 31:28, 55)
- Esau kisses Jacob when they reunite (Genesis 33:4)
- Joseph kisses his brothers when he reveals himself (Genesis 45:15)
- Aaron and Moses kiss when they are reunited (Exodus 4:27)
- Naomi kisses her daughters then Orpah kisses Naomi before returning to Moab (Ruth 1:9, 14)
- Jonathan and David kiss before David runs from Saul (1 Samuel 20:41)
- Absalom kisses David when they are reunited following Amnon's murder (2 Samuel 14:33)
- Men kiss Absalom at the gate (2 Samuel 15:5)
- David kisses Barzillai when returning to Jerusalem after Absalom is killed (2 Samuel 19:39)
- Joab kisses Amasa before killing him (2 Samuel 20:9)
- Elisha wants to kiss his father and mother before following Elijah (1 Kings 19:20)

In each event, the theme of betrayal and/or separation is present. Since some, especially those with Absalom, have great affinity with the Gospel narratives, it would appear that is the reason Matthew and Mark chose to describe Judas' actions using κατεφίλησαν rather than with φιλέω .

There also may be an allusion to Psalm 84 (85):

> <sup>1</sup> Regarding completion. Pertaining to the sons of Kore. A Psalm. <sup>2(1)</sup> You took pleasure Lord, in your land; you turned away the captivity of Iakob. <sup>3(2)</sup>  You forgave your people their acts of lawlessness; you covered all their sins. *Interlude on strings* <sup>4(3)</sup>  You put a stop to all your wrath; you turned away from your hot anger. <sup>5(4)</sup>  Bring us back O God of our deliverance, and turn away your anger from us. <sup>6(5)</sup>  Surely, you will not be angry with us forever or prolong your anger from generation to generation? <sup>7(6)</sup>  O God when it is you who brings us back you will revive us, and your people will be glad in you. <sup>8(7)</sup> Show us O Lord, your mercy, and your deliverance may you grant us. <sup>9(8)</sup>  I will hear what the Lord God will speak with me, because he will speak peace to his people and to his devout and to those who turn to him their heart. <sup>10(9)</sup>  But for those who fear him his deliverance is at hand, that glory may encamp in our land. **<sup>11(10)</sup> Mercy and truth met; righteousness and peace kissed.** <sup>12(11)</sup>  Truth sprouted from the ground, and righteousness peered down from the sky. <sup>13(12)</sup>  Indeed, the Lord will give kindness, and our land will yield its crop. <sup>14(13)</sup>  Righteousness will go before him and will place his steps in the way.[(NET)](http://ccat.sas.upenn.edu/nets/edition/24-ps-nets.pdf)

It may seem strange to consider the symbolism of Jesus (as righteousness) kissing Judas (as peace), however there is a sense of εἰρήνη which is used between [departing friends](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G1515&t=KJV). Considering Judas a "friend" echoes Psalm 41 which John cites (13:18) in the Final Discourse. Of course there is also the symbolism of the death of Jesus making peace with God (Romans 5:1).

Answer (score 0):

Peace.

The “kiss” of Judas signifies the speaking of “good words and fair speeches” in order to deceive the hearts of the simple.

Many have followed and still follow in the footsteps of Judas as they use good words to flatter the unsuspecting people with flattering lips ….and they come to take Jesus (the keeping of the “daily” sacrifice of our Lord) out of the lives of those who fall victim to their feigned words.

They use “flattering lips”….a feigned “kiss” …. to speak those flattering words to deceive….and they successfully take Jesus out of the lives of those who listen to them.

As Paul stated, we are to salute each other with a “holy kiss”.

Yet, their “kiss” is not holy but feigned as they “salute” others with good words and fair speeches in order to deceive.

> Romans 16:16-18 KJV (16)  *Salute one another **with an holy kiss**. The
>   churches of Christ salute you.*

Those who use a feigned “kiss” toward us cause divisions among us and put up stumbling blocks (their teachings and commandments of men that also divide us) contrary to the teaching which we have learned (to have love for one another).  We are to avoid them.

> (17)  ***Now I beseech you, brethren, mark them which cause divisions and
>   offences contrary to the doctrine which ye have learned; and avoid
>   them.***

As Judas, they do these things for money’s sake as they serve for their own belly.  Their feigned "kiss"  = good words and fair speeches.

> (18)  ***For they that are such serve not our Lord Jesus Christ, but
>   their own belly; and by good words and fair speeches deceive the
>   hearts of the simple.***

Through covetousness shall they with feigned words (the flattering lips….the “kiss” of Judas) make merchandise of you.   Judas received his 30 pieces of silver in his betrayal of Jesus.

> 2 Peter 2:3 KJV (3)  ***And through covetousness shall they with feigned
>   words make merchandise of you:*** whose judgment now of a long time
>   lingereth not, and their damnation slumbereth not.

They come to take Jesus away out of our lives…taking away the keeping of His “daily” sacrifice.

If we always bear about the dying of the Lord Jesus (the keeping of His daily sacrifice) in this mortal  body, then the life also of Jesus will be made manifest in our outer mortal flesh giving our bodies His eternal life in this earth.

> 2 Corinthians 4:10-11 KJV (10)  ***Always bearing about in the body the
>   dying of the Lord Jesus, that the life also of Jesus might be made
>   manifest in our body***. (11)  For we which live are alway delivered unto
>   death for Jesus' sake, **that the life also of Jesus might be made
>   manifest in our mortal flesh.**

There will be scoffers who will say “where is the promise of His coming”.  Where is His eternal life in this earth for all have died?  Their judgment is not lingering...it is not sleeping..as they are perishing from this earth under His wrath that is revealed from Heaven as they speak.

> 2 Peter 3:3-4 KJV (3)  *Knowing this first, that there shall come in
>   the last days scoffers, walking after their own lusts, (4)  And
>   saying, **Where is the promise of his coming?** for since the fathers fell
>   asleep, all things continue as they were from the beginning of the
>   creation.*

When we keep His “daily” in the temple of our mortal bodies, then they have no power to deceive us.Jesus teaches us “daily” to have love for one another and we are to keep His daily sacrifice and die to sin daily.

But if we forget (fall “asleep”), then they use this “power of darkness” to deceive us with their  flattering lips….the “kiss” of Judas.   Judas gave the sign of the kiss to those who follow after him in this.  The person who falls victim to the flattering lips can easily be taken.

> Luke 22:53 KJV (53)  ***When I was daily with you in the temple, ye
>   stretched forth no hands against me: but this is your hour, and the
>   power of darkness.***

Why “sleep”…being forgetful to do His commandment to have love for one another?

If we fall “asleep”, then we can be deceived by the temptation of those who come with a feigned “kiss” in order to betray the Son of man so that His eternal life is never made manifest in our mortal bodies.   They have the power to deceive us if we fall “asleep” to His commandment to have love for one another. We must arise...awake to His righteousness...and use our words always with grace and peace...lest they come and deceive us in our forgetfulness.

> Luke 22:46-48 KJV (46)  *And said unto them, **Why sleep ye? rise and
>   pray, lest ye enter into temptation.** (47)  And while he yet spake,
>   behold a multitude, and he that was called Judas, one of the twelve,
>   went before them, and drew near unto Jesus to kiss him. (48)  But
>   Jesus said unto him, Judas, betrayest thou the Son of man with a kiss?*

If we always remember to keep His commandment….

> Proverbs 6:20-26 KJV (20)  ***My son, keep thy father's commandment,*** and
>   forsake not the law of thy mother: (21)  Bind them continually upon
>   thine heart, and tie them about thy neck. (22)  When thou goest, it
>   shall lead thee; when thou sleepest, it shall keep thee; and when thou
>   awakest, it shall talk with thee. (23)  For the commandment is a lamp;
>   and the law is light; and reproofs of instruction are the way of life:

…then we shall not fall victim to the flattery of the tongue of a “strange woman”….a person who preaches strange things for money’s sake.

> (24)  ***To keep thee from the evil woman, from the flattery of the
>   tongue of a strange woman.*** (25)  Lust not after her beauty in thine
>   heart; neither let her take thee with her eyelids.

The “adulteress” hunts covertly for the “Precious Life” of Jesus and makes merchandise of those that they flatter with feigned words.

> (26)  *For by means of a whorish woman a man is brought to a piece of
>   bread: **and the adulteress will hunt for the precious life***.

A GREAT MULTITUDE are following in the footsteps of Judas and are coming forth unto us with a feigned “kiss”….the flattering lips….in order to take the keeping of His “daily” sacrifice out of our lives so that the life of Jesus is never made manifest in our mortal bodies.  They are doing this for money’s sake.

The great multitude who is “with Judas” in his single purpose have “swords” as they cause divisions among us.  They come with staves...with their teachings for doctrines the commandments of men that cause us to stumble as we use their handwritings of church dogmas to judge others...which is living after the flesh and not after the Spirit.

> Mark 14:43-44 KJV (43)  *And immediately, while he yet spake, cometh
>   Judas, one of the twelve, **and with him a great multitude with swords
>   and staves, from the chief priests and the scribes and the elders.**
>   (44)  And he that betrayed him had given them a token, saying,
>   Whomsoever I shall kiss, that same is he; take him, and lead him away
>   safely.*

The manifest eternal life of Jesus in our mortal bodies shrinks away by the flattering lips of the multitude of church leaders that are following after Judas.  They are taking the eternal life of Jesus away as they take the keeping of His daily sacrifice out of our lives.   They take away Jesus “securely”.

The Son of man “goes” …shrinks away out of sight…as it is written of Him but woe unto that man by whom the Son of man is betrayed.   His eternal life is being cut off from this earth by them.

> Matthew 26:24-25 KJV (24)  ***The Son of man goeth as it is written of
>   him: but woe unto that man by whom the Son of man is betrayed***! it had
>   been good for that man if he had not been born. (25)  Then Judas,
>   which betrayed him, answered and said, Master, is it I? He said unto
>   him, Thou hast said.

Jesus was dead and is alive.  He is risen now so that we may have His eternal life in the here-and-now.  But the multitudes are taking the “I am”….I exist….I am risen…and are casting this truth to the ground as they preach that we have to die and go to Heaven when Jesus already died for us and is alive now forevermore.   They are preaching their covenant with death and their agreement with the grave when Jesus already died for us and is risen.

They say that they seek Jesus but they take His truth (the “I am” of Jesus) and are casting it to the ground in the ears of those that they are deceiving.

> John 18:4-6 KJV (4)  *Jesus therefore, knowing all things that should
>   come upon him, went forth, and said unto them, Whom seek ye?*

The “I am” of Jesus is being denied by those who betray His eternal life from ever appearing in this earth.

> (5)  *They answered him, Jesus of Nazareth. **Jesus saith unto them, I am**
>   he. And Judas also, which betrayed him, stood with them. (6)  As soon
>   then **as he had said unto them, I am he, they went backward, and fell
>   to the ground.***

Jesus:  I am He that lives and was dead and behold I am alive forevermore.  Amen = firm, Truth.

He has the keys of the grave and death:   by the keeping of His daily sacrifice in our bodies (He was dead…and we are to follow Him and die to sin daily), then we are to also have His eternal life NOW (behold, I am alive forevermore).

> Revelation 1:18 KJV (18)  ***I am he that liveth, and was dead; and,
>   behold, I am alive for evermore, Amen; and have the keys of hell and
>   of death.***

As He lives, we shall also live as He was dead and is alive now forevermore.   He will manifest Himself to us as His life within us shall be made manifest in our mortal flesh.

> John 14:19-21 KJV (19)  *Yet a little while, and the world seeth me no
>   more; but ye see me: **because I live, ye shall live also.** (20)  At that
>   day ye shall know that I am in my Father, and ye in me, and I in you.
>   (21)  He that hath my commandments, and keepeth them, he it is that
>   loveth me: and he that loveth me shall be loved of my Father, and I
>   will love him, and will manifest myself to him.*

But the multitudes of false teachers that are with Judas (a host was given him) come forth to take the “daily” sacrifice out of our lives so that the place of His sanctuary (our mortal body which is the temple of the Holy Spirit) is cast down.   We perish from this earth without the appearing of His eternal life.  The mortal body is cast down to the grave.    His life is being aborted as the Son of man shrinks away out of sight from this earth.

> Daniel 8:11-12 KJV (11)  Yea, he magnified himself even to the prince
>   of the host, and by him the daily sacrifice was taken away, and the
>   place of his sanctuary was cast down.

A multitude of people follow after Judas in their covetousness for money and use of feigned words (the “kiss” of the flattering lips) and they cast the truth to the ground (the “I am” of Jesus)….and they practice and prosper at it.

> (12)  *And an host was given him **against the daily sacrifice** by reason
>   of transgression, and it cast down the truth to the ground; and it
>   practised, and prospered.*

Who shall declare His generation?

His eternal life is being cut out of the land of the living by the wicked and the rich multitudes that are following in the footsteps of Judas.

> Isaiah 53:8-9 KJV (8)  *He was taken from prison and from judgment: and
>   who shall declare his generation? **for he was cut off out of the land
>   of the living:** for the transgression of my people was he stricken.*

His “death” = His DEATHS (plural) in Isaiah 53:9…. as His eternal life is being prevented from appearing in this earth as it is being cut out of the earth.

The wicked and the rich are using deceit when Jesus did not.  They do “violence” as they are casting down the temple of our mortal bodies to the grave by their deceit.   Jesus did not do these things and are not following in the footsteps of Jesus.

> *(9)  And he made his grave with the wicked, and with the rich **in his
>   death;** because he had done no violence, neither was any deceit in his
>   mouth*.

Many will not want to hear about His eternal life in the here-and-now.  He IS RISEN now so that we may have His eternal life now.  They do not want His disciples to come “by night” and steal their congregations where all are “asleep” and preach to the people that “He IS RISEN from the dead”.

> Matthew 27:62-66 KJV (62)  *Now the next day, that followed the day of
>   the preparation, the chief priests and Pharisees came together unto
>   Pilate, (63)  Saying, Sir, we remember that that deceiver said, while
>   he was yet alive, After three days I will rise again. (64)  **Command
>   therefore that the sepulchre be made sure** until the third day, lest
>   his disciples come by night, and steal him away, **and say unto the
>   people, He is risen from the dead:** so the last error shall be worse
>   than the first.*

They want to make the tomb a sure thing for their listeners and they seal it with the handwriting of church dogmas….preaching their covenant with death and their agreement with the grave.

> (65)  *Pilate said unto them, Ye have a watch: go your way, make it as
>   sure as ye can. (66)  **So they went, and made the sepulchre sure,
>   sealing the stone,** and setting a watc*h.

He takes the handwriting of the church scribes out of the way which keeps us in their “tomb”  and nails it to His cross as we are forgiven for the worshipping and serving of it.   We were dead in our sins and the uncircumcision of our flesh as we once served the handwriting and used it to judge others and served the flesh: envy, strife, hatred of one another.

> Colossians 2:13-15 KJV (13)  *And you, being dead in your sins and the
>   uncircumcision of your flesh, hath he quickened together with him,
>   having forgiven you all trespasses; (14)  **Blotting out the handwriting
>   of ordinances that was against us, which was contrary to us, and took
>   it out of the way, nailing it to his cross;** (15)  And having spoiled
>   principalities and powers, he made a shew of them openly, triumphing
>   over them in it.*

Do not let a man who is “puffed up” by his fleshly mind judge you with his handwriting of church dogmas that was wrested from the Scriptures by the church scribes.

> Colossians 2:16-22 KJV (16)  *L**et no man therefore judge you** in meat,
>   or in drink, or in respect of an holyday, or of the new moon, or of
>   the sabbath days: (17)  Which are a shadow of things to come; but the
>   body is of Christ.*

Let no man beguile you of your reward....the appearing eternal life of Jesus in our mortal body.    **To be puffed up =growth.**

> (18)  *Let no man beguile you of your reward in a voluntary humility
>   and worshipping of angels, intruding into those things which he hath
>   not seen, **vainly puffed up by his fleshly mind**,*

Such a person is not holding the Head.  He does not have the mind of Christ but has a fleshly mind and is wresting the Scriptures to his own destruction from off this earth as his mortal body perishes without the life of Jesus appearing.

> (19)  ***And not holding the Head,*** from which all the body by joints and
>   bands having nourishment ministered, and knit together, increaseth
>   with the increase of God.

Why be subject to their dogmas…to their ordinances (Greek: dogmas)…to their commandments and doctrines of men written down by the scribes?

> (20)  ***Wherefore if ye be dead with Christ from the rudiments of the
>   world, why, as though living in the world, are ye subject to
>   ordinances,***

We perish from this earth by the using of them.  The woman in the garden added her own carnal commandment (neither shall you touch it) to God's commandment and then presented it as though God commanded it to keep. Fleshly-minded Men are doing the same today with their handwriting of church dogmas that they want you to keep and serve and worship.

> (21)  ***(Touch not; taste not; handle not; (22)  Which all are to perish
>   with the using;) after the commandments and doctrines of men?***

The minister (the treasurer over the house of God) who is “Shebna”…meaning “growth”( as he is puffed up in his fleshly mind)…is to be removed from the being overseer of the church so that we may serve the Lord only.

> Isaiah 22:15-21 KJV (15)  *Thus saith the Lord GOD of hosts, Go, get
>   thee **unto this treasurer, even unto Shebna,** which is over the house,
>   and say,*

Shebna (meaning "growth" as he is puffed up in his fleshly mind) hewed himself a tomb on high and engraved a handwriting of church dogmas for others to serve…and many perish by the serving them in the tomb of their church.

Why be subject to their handwriting of dogmas which are written by a church scribe/scribes (Shebna was a scribe also and who was puffed up with his fleshly mind as his name suggests)?  What is this you are doing here what is this you have here...a highly esteemed handwriting engraved for others to serve and perish by the serving of?

> (16)  *What hast thou here? and whom hast thou here, **that thou hast
>   hewed thee out a sepulchre here,** as he that heweth him out a sepulchre
>   on high, and that graveth an habitation for himself in a rock? (17) 
>   Behold, the LORD will carry thee away with a mighty captivity, and
>   will surely cover thee.*

The Lord takes away the stone.  He takes away the handwriting that is contrary to us and is against us and makes an open show of it..….rolling away the circle (“ball”) into a large country (an open show of those who engraved it). He takes away their power over us.

> (18)  ***He will surely violently turn and toss thee like a ball into a
>   large country: there shalt thou die, and there the chariots of thy
>   glory shall be the shame of thy lord's house.*** (19)  And I will drive
>   thee from thy station, and from thy state shall he pull thee down.
>   (20)  And it shall come to pass in that day, that I will call my
>   servant Eliakim the son of Hilkiah: (21)  And I will clothe him with
>   thy robe, and strengthen him with thy girdle, and I will commit thy
>   government into his hand: and he shall be a father to the inhabitants
>   of Jerusalem, and to the house of Judah.

Answer (score 0):

that the kiss is prophetic, there is no doubt, but in my opinion, when Jesus called Judas "friend", He, like a good Shepherd, was bitter in his heart when he saw one of his sheep leave his own flock forever. . . Jesus looked at him with the eyes of extreme compassion and knew that his true love was not enough to change the life of Judas, who gave his eternal life to the devil (probably not knowing what would happen after his death as disturbed man because after the betrayal, Satan left him with his deep guilt)
The Gospel says that "and then Satan was in Judas" (Luke 22: 3), the kiss was a provocation of the devil, mocking Jesus, not knowing that He would rise from the death he had caused and that Jesus would take the key to the kingdom forever, as an eternal winner !!!
and also, to prove that Jesus was an ordinary man, his appearance was that of a normal worker and could be mistaken for other men and kissing him, Judas would separate him from the others - since the kiss represented respect and devotion and Jesus was his Master ( Rabbi). 
But nothing happens without reason.  It is all implicitly linked in God's mystery! It had to happen that way, the act of betrayal had to come from someone close to Jesus to fulfill God's purpose and Judas had a heart that was inclined towards evil! The Bible does not say what the tribe of Judas was, but some speculations say it was from Dan; in that case, Jacob's prophetic words proceed (Genesis 49: 16-17).
God knows everything, Satan doesn't!

Answer (score -1):

I am amazed at the various perceptions Christians have of Judas and primarily the idea that he is the betrayer. I wish to state with conviction and proof(I will not provide it now) that Judas is not the betrayer and the "kiss" was not a sign to identify Jesus. I am thrilled to know the answer which for 2000 years remained unknown to the Christian world. Judas Iscariot was the first disciple of Jesus and was handpicked for his special qualities. Jesus made Judas his right hand man, his steward, treasurer, estate manager, security/intelligence officer and PRO. But who was Judas? The gospels have very little information about him except that he was the son of Simon and he was a thief, a sly pick-pocket and a real crook. A leader of a great Christian church, who is alive today called him a "dirty, greedy, liar", that is equivalent to what the Gospels have already said. He is also regarded as an assassin or murderer.
                    My view is different. As his name denotes he was the first born in his family hence dedicated to God. Like Jesus, Judas was a Judean and could have been a close relative. He was a Nazarene(Zealot,rebel, Sicarii or assassin who were trained to kill and also get killed). As Jesus steward he must have been educated and must have been thorough with the scriptures. According to the Jewish historian Josephus, the Zealots never betrayed their own people even under extreme forms of torture. Money meant nothing to him. Judas was very close to Jesus. The only other person who was a confidante was Mary Magdalene a very rich person and principal donor to Jesus cause, who could also be a close relative of Jesus. One must also include Lazarus another relative, who was on the "hit list". The position of a steward is a post of great accountability and absolute trust(it is even more when Jesus is the master. It is not meant for a common thief or a cheap crook)and demands very hard work and exceptional organizational skills. To say that Judas was a thief reflects poorly on Jesus judgement, implying that Jesus did not have the intelligence to make a good decision. This is unacceptable for me but not for Christians. At the last supper Jesus honors Judas by seating him in the chair of honor on his right hand and giving him the sup(the first morsel of the feast) to indicate the person the master loves the most. For Judas it was a great moment, because it meant that he was chosen to die with Jesus. Judas had loads of money. In the middle of the meal Jesus assigns an urgent but secret task to Judas. None of the disciples including the Gospels have any idea what it was, except Judas. He leaves immediately. He completes his work(money to be distributed to the orphans, the poor and the widows), and while returning he is trapped and arrested and dragged to Gethesmane by the soldiers. There was no need to identify Jesus, anyone could do it among the crowd, besides Peter, James and John were standing behind Jesus. Judas calls Jesus "master" and kisses him because he is not going to meet him again. In the temple Judas throws the bribe money into the temple and incurs the sin of high sacriliege and punishment  of death. His instantly taken away and brutally impaled and hauled up for everyone to see. His bowels come out. Judas mission is over. Jesus is crucified a few hours later. There is not a single word of  Christian sympathy in the whole of the New Testament for Judas. He is branded a traitor forever. But death never comes cheap. To die for a cause and for the person who loved him, Judas never begged for his life to be spared, any other person would have done it, especially a low level thief. Judas fulfilled the greatest commandment: " Greater love than this no man has than a man lay down his life for his friend". That is all.

Comment: Normally, I just let 'divergent' views pass w/o comment. This one is totally speculative, without any support whatsoever from text or secondary sources. Besides that, it runs contradictory to numerous passages that describe Judas as the 'snake that strikes the heel' of Christ. If you truly believe what you've stated, provide sources to back it up. Otherwise, if you are simply being contrarian, then you are being dishonest with the text AND your audience.

Answer (score -1):

The Bible says, Judas said “The one I kiss is the man; arrest him"
To show love to your loved ones, kiss was the sign to share love. Judas was thinking, that Jesus did not know that he has told the soldiers, the one I kiss is the man to arrest , he been thinking Jesus won't know this at all. So it was just the signal to show Jesus, that he loves him so much.
So, in this scene take "kiss" signal of betraying and symbol of love.